# Operation not permitted

Tags: php, linux, centos

Из-за чего может быть вот такая ошибка?

```
strace -p  4623
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
```

Comment: вероятно, требуются привилегии суперпользователя. запускайте программу от имени пользователя *root*, или (если установлена) программы *sudo*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это только одна из возможных причин, так же могут быть а) попытки повторного присоединения, б) параметры настроек, которые влияют на то, какой именно процесс мы пытаемся трассировать.